# Access function propertes (.caller) without specifying it's own name

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript you can access a function's "functional properties", for instance `caller`. (Actually, I do not even know if the "functional property" is a right word.)

For example:

```
func0 = function() {
   console.log(typeof func0.caller)
}
func1 = func0
func1()
var o = { func2: func0, func3: function(){ console.log(typeof o.func3.caller) } }
o.func2()
o.func3()
```

As you can see, you must provide a function name before you can add `.caller`. But if the function is anonymous or for some reason I do not want to use the name (maybe I plan to rename the fucntion in the future): can I still access caller?

Comment: `arguments.callee` will give you a reference to the current function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are accessing is the arguments object that is 'assigned' to every function. So you don't use the function name. You use the arguments object.

arguments object acts like an array, so arguments[0] returns the first argument passed to the function.

```
arguments.length 
// a property of the arguments object that tells you how many arguments the function has

arguments.caller
// reference to the function that invoked the current function.

arguments.callee() will call the function recursively. Its a reference to the currently executing function.
```

Is that what you mean?

```
Use arguments.callee.caller
```

It seems that the reason this works is because arguments.callee is giving you a reference to the function that is currently executing, and then arguments.caller is referencing the function that *invoked* that function (which is actually the same function). Maybe that is why using arguments.caller is not advisable.

Comment: Then this snippet should work, but it outputs `undefined`: `func0 = function() { console.log(typeof arguments.caller) }; func0()`

Comment: I think that may be because the caller property is obsolete. I don't think you're supposed to rely on it.If you need a reference to the current function. then use arguments.callee

Comment: Can you please update your answer so I can accept it as correct?